# how to write a loop to do the calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my basic mysql query, it's used to calculate the daily user numbers, so I need to execute this from 2012-01-30 till 2012-02-19, instead of modified it manually, is there any good method?

```
select count(distinct user) FROM video WHERE date >= '2012-01-30 00:00' AND date <= '2012-01-30 23:55';


select count(distinct user) FROM video WHERE date >= '2012-01-31 00:00' AND date <= '2012-01-31 23:55';

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT user) FROM video
WHERE date >= '2012-01-30 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2012-02-19 00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Comment: or `date_pl < '2012-02-20 00:00'`

Comment: @GermannArlington - are you sure about that? Notice the OP's statement above is using `date_pl` as the ending date of the range. It's just that the range is always one day.

Comment: I always thought that `x <= someValue` is equivalent to `x < (someValue + minimumIncrement)` and this is exactly what I have done.
The "or" part is NOT part of the suggested code

Comment: @GermannArlington - I see what you're saying, yes that would work just as well, I didn't read it properly. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Thanks, but my date value is in minute scale, so I have entries like 2012-01-30 00:00, 2012-01-30 00:05...2012-01-30 23:50, if I write group by date, then I will have tons of results like 2012-01-30 00:00 5 users, 2012-01-30 00:05 10 users....instead of by day, do you see what I mean?

Comment: @manxing - I've updated my answer with a modified solution to solve that problem.